# $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ when $f$ is not injective function.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

> $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$

I know that $f$ should be injective to satisfy this equation. However, in some constant function, I think it is also satisfied. For example,

let $f(x) = (3)$ and $x \in X$. $A$ and $B$ is subset of $X$.

let $A = (1, 2, 3)$, $B = (3, 4, 5)$. Then, $A \cap B = (3)$. $f(A \cap B) = (3)$.

$f(A) = (3)$ and $f(B) = (3)$. Thus, $f(A) \cap f(B) = (3)$.

However, $f$ is not injective. Is there any mistake?

Comment: If $A, B$ are disjoint but non-empty? Sure it can happen that $f[A\cap B] = f[A]\cap f[B]$, but if it does for all $A, B\subseteq X$, then $f$ is necessarily injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is injective iff $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ **for every pair $A, B$ of subsets of the domain of $f$** (let me know in a comment if you need help with proving that). However that fact doesn't preclude the possibility that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for some subsets of the domain of a function $f$ that is not injective. E.g., it will always be the case, for any $f$, if $A = B = \emptyset$ or $A = B = \mathrm{dom}(f)$.

In your example, if you take $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$, then $f(A \cap B) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but $f(A) \cap f(B) = \{3\} \cap \{3\} = \{3\}$.